# Getting NodeJS delete route non functioning

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

I did the registration portion successfully now I am trying to delete the registered user by `id` . This is how I did

**user controller**

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

module.exports.register = (req, res, next) =>{  

    var user = new User();
    user.fullName = req.body.fullName;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
    user.save((err, doc) =>{
        if(!err)
            res.send(doc);
        else{
            if (err.code == 11000)
                    res.status(422).send(["Entered duplicate email address. Please check"]);
            else
            return next(err);
            }
    });
}
```

And in my **index router**

```
const express = require ('express');
const router = express.Router();
const ctrlUser = require ('../controllers/user.controller.js');

// routing functions 

router.post('/register' , ctrlUser.register);

router.delete('/:userId' , (req, res, next) =>{

    User.remove({_id: req.params.userId})
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200).send(["Deleted"]);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        if (err.code == 500)
                    res.status(500).send(["Didn't get deleted"]);
            else
            return next(err);
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

*When I am testing in postman I am not getting any response. Where did I make the mistake ? Something am I missing out ?*

**EDIT:-** **Including user.model**

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

//define user schema 
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Full name can't be empty"
                },
    email :     {
                type: String,
                required: "Email can't be empty",
                unique: true
                },
    password :  {
                type: String,
                required: "Password can't be empty",
                minlength: [6 ,"Password must be atleast 6 character long"]
                },  
    phoneNumber :   {
                type: String,
                required: "Reqired for further contact.Can't be empty"
                },
    saltSecret: String //this is user for encryption and decryption of password
});
mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: in index file User is not defined.

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary do I need to define model or controller ? I have defined the controller by `ctrlUser` . So instead of `User` will it be `ctrlUser` ?

Comment: You better have separate model file and export that model and include it where ever you need. So here you have to again defined `User`. if you want to look simple example :https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary I do have separate user  model js file. I have added in EDITS.

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary Yes , I  got it . Thanks for clarifying

Comment: did it solved the problem?

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary yes it did